# Android - creating a custom listView that continues through 2 listViews

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am building an Android Application and I have 4 custom ListViews in one activity. Due to the length of the list items, 2 of the lists are scrollable and 2 of the list are not. At first, I minimized the height of the 2 listViews that did not have a scrollbar since their data can be shown right away. However, the other 2 listViews have a lot of data that they still need scrolling even after maximizing the space allotted on the screen.

The solution I have in mind is to make a "multi-column" continuous customListView. The concept is similar to the columns in the newspaper where 1 article would go from top to bottom in one column and continue on the next column. However, I haven't found a property of a listView that allows me to split it into to two and display data the way I want it to. In this way, all the list data would be displayed and there will be no need for a scrollbar.

I know a quick and dirty solution would be to generate as much listViews as I need to and just figure out what part of the arrayList data to split and give to them for display. However, this solution is ugly and undesirable because if the number of arrayList data changes, then the solution won't hold any more. I want an elegant solution.

How can I do this?

Comment: So, your issue is that the content of a list view is off screen and you don't want it to be?

Comment: Yes, and the solution I want is to display everything all at once using a "multi-column" listView. I have tried setting the font size to the smallest possible font but there are still data that aren't getting displayed.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be using a list view. The list view is designed to have arbitrary content off screen. You will have you swing your own view to get the results exactly as you want.

Comment: Well, any alternatives in mind? A listView is the most efficient way to display a list of data wherein it takes care of displaying data automatically for you. Is what I have in mind in the question above not possible or no one has tried it yet?

Comment: The problem is not that it is not possible; it is, just hard because that is not what the view is designed for. Even if you get it to work right on a couple of devices, there will be thousands more that your design simply will not look valid for. Your easiest option it to create your own view that will take a collection of content and draw it scaled to fit within its bounds.

Comment: [FlowLayout](https://github.com/ApmeM/android-flowlayout) + ScrollView?

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA I'll check with using Grid Views.

Comment: @karaokyo sorry but I don't quite get how I'm supposed to use flowLayout in this one. I want to be able to "extend" my listView into to separate columns if there are still list data that are off screen.

Comment: Gridviews are also designed to scroll. The exact same problem is still present: they both extends AbsListView.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA but with gridViews, I can have columns in my layout already so there's a higher chance that I can display more data given the same space.

Comment: You might consider a table layout with a custom table row implementation that is responsible for scaling the content.

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA will check it out. Thank you for the lead.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a `GridView`. I changed my `ListView` to a `GridView` as such:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/myIdHere"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="60"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false">
</GridView>
```

And then I changed the `ListView` calls in my activity to `GridView` and that was it. Since custom gridViews also uses a `BaseAdapter`, I was able to easily reuse my code easily.